# Initializing std::string with const char * results in gibberish

Tags: c++, string

I use rapidjson to read JSON files, and some of the values are string. Now, rapidjson's `GetString()` method returns a `const char *`. I'd like to store this in `std::string`, though. I've tried this:

```
const char* foo = d["foo"].GetString();
printf("Foo: %s\n", foo); // Prints correctly

std::string fooStr(foo);
printf("FooString: %s\n", fooStr); // Gibberish
```

How do I get the correct `std::string`?

Comment: `%s` must take a `char *`, not a `std::string`. Use `fooStr.c_str()` there.  Also, what is `d` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb d is the rapidjson document.

Comment: It's not clear from your question whether `foo` is pointing to valid storage, or destroyed storage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't pass `std::string` directly to `printf`. It's a C-style variadic function, that only works with C-compatible types, not (non-trivial) C++ classes. In particular, the `%s` specifier requires its matching argument to be a pointer to C-style string (a zero-terminated character array), of type `const char *`.

You can either use a C++ stream:

```
std::cout << "FooString: " << fooStr << '\n';
```

or extract a C-style pointer from the string:

```
printf("FooString: %s\n", fooStr.c_str());
```

You should also enable compiler warnings; that should tell you exactly what's wrong.

Comment: Ah, that's it. I just checked the debugger and the string indeed has the correct value in it. Duh. Thanks, I'll accept your answer asap. :)

Comment: I prefer C++ streams since they're specifically C++ constructs but that's a matter of taste. Not sure if there's any reason here to prefer one over another

Answer (score 2):

To convert string to const char* use string::c_str()